# adding items to array during foreach on the array

Tags: php

I wish to run a foreach on a load of ID's.
However each of the items in the foreach is a select query and if it finds more ID's they need to be added to the array that is being run in the foreach.
E.g

```
$ids = array();     
foreach($ids as $id)
    {
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE otherid = $id;
    foreach ($query2->result_array() as $row)
         {
         array_push($array, $row['id']);
         }
    }
```

This is obviously pseudocode so no need to correct my SQL etc. I just need for the foreach to continue if it finds more ID's.

Possible?

I have tried adding an & here -> `foreach($ids as &$id)` as somebody else on here has suggested in a similar question. This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why can't you fetch all IDs at once?

Comment: Is a multi-level database that requires items to be conditionally stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreach` actually makes a copy of your array to loop though, you will need to use `while`.

```
while(list($id_key, $id) = each($ids)){
    //your code
    $ids[] = $row[id];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to just reference the original array ie

```
   foreach ($query2->result_array() as $row)
     {
       $id[] = $row;
     }
```

This will automatically assign an auto incremented key to the the new array element and add it to the $id array. I assume this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate with a variable:

```
$ids = array();     
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($ids)) {
    $query2->query(SELECT id FROM table WHERE otherid = $ids[$i]);
    foreach ($query2->result_array() as $row)
        $ids []= $row['id'];
    $i++;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For similar problems, I have always used two different arrays. Such code can run a query for every id only one time. I don't think it would be possible with only one array+foreach;

The following code is pretty simple. It keeps finding new ids until there are no new ids.

```
$ids = array();
$new = array();
$new = $ids;

do {
    foreach($new as $n) {
        $new = array();
        //// HERE PUT YOUR CODE TO RUN A QUERY AND MAYBE PUSH A NEW ID TO $new \\\\
    }
    $ids = array_merge($ids,$new);
} while (count($new)!==0);
```